# Reusable component with set Input() any type is a good practice?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, reference, typescript-typings

I created a reusable component that takes a list of elements of the type any. He works on these elements and in the case of pressing the button returns the state of the list he got. I'm worried about losing typing in this case. Is this a safe solution? I would like the component to be reusable. Is it possible to dynamically cast from any type to a different type?

I tried to cast object in set Input() but it is not possible

```js
export class ReusableTableComponent {
  @Input() list: any[];
  @Output() selectedItems: EventEmmiter = new EventEmmiter<any>;
  selectedItemsList: any[] = [];

  emitChanges() {
  this.selectedItems.emit(this.selectedItemsList)}

}
```

The problem is, eventEmmiter is returning object type not specific type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a generic type:

```
export class ReusableTableComponent {
  @Input() list: T[];
  @Output() selectedItems: EventEmmiter = new EventEmmiter<T>;
  selectedItemsList: T[] = [];

  emitChanges() {
  this.selectedItems.emit(this.selectedItemsList)}

}
```

Read more about generic types in TypeScript here:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Comment: Thanks but how i van pass Type to input from patent component ?

Comment: there are an interesting discussion about your question in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893991/declare-a-component-with-generic-type?rq=1, but I don't know if relative to your question

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use dynamic types in Typescript

```
export class ReusableTableComponent<LIST, EVENTLIST> {
  @Input() list: LIST[];
  @Output() selectedItems: EventEmmiter = new EventEmmiter<EVENTLIST>;
  selectedItemsList: EVENTLIST[] = [];

  emitChanges() {
  this.selectedItems.emit(this.selectedItemsList)}

}
```

Comment: Ok its good, but how i can pass Type by Input from parent component ? [list]=" objects[]" not working

Comment: can you create a stackblitz

Comment: I cant now, writing on phone

Comment: @Blackboy here is a stackblitz on how you could create your component and pass in the type, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vj13j