# How to pass @input() property with generic type T in an component ( @Input() ItemList: T[] = [];)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building an component which accept an @Input() property called itemList as follows,

```
@Input() ItemList: T[] = [];
```

is there a way to pass @Input property of type T from parent to the child component in angular 5?

any example would be helpful.  As we are using AOT , so it is not that straight forward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Declare a component with generic type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893991/declare-a-component-with-generic-type)

Comment: I already check this one, before posting this question. unfortunately, it does not answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to define generic type in class definition.

Example:

```
export class MyListComponent<T> implements OnInit {
   @Input() itemList: T[] = [];

   ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: assume your component MyListComponent<T> is a child component. so can you please add the code of how, parent component will use this child component , specifically passing an @Input property of type T?

Comment: In HTML: `<my-list-component [itemList]="yourList"></my-list-component>`.

Comment: In TS: `@ViewChild(MyListComponent) listComponent: MyListComponent<ItemList>`.