# How to "pass down" TypeScript type to Angular component @Input decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple Angular component to display a dropdown menu. My initial pass had this as the inputs/output:

```
 @Input() options: OptionType[] = [];
 @Input() selectedOption: OptionType = { name: '', value: '' };

 @Output() onChangeEvent = new EventEmitter<OptionType>();
```

...where `OptionType` is:

```
type OptionType = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}
```

The problem is that callers of this component usually have limited possible values for both `name` and `value`. For example, I might an option set that is:

```
[
{name: 'No', value: 'no'},
{name: 'Yes', value: 'yes'}
]
```

In the type declared by the parent, I restrict the possible types to what you see above, and that leads to a collision between, for example, `'no' | 'yes'` and `string`.

What I'd like to be able to do is to say that the main `OptionType` of this component should be inherited from the caller. I know this kind of thing is generally done with TypeScript generics, but I don't know how to do what I want in this context, or even if such a thing is possible/smart.

Comment: You want to use a generic component class: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893991/declare-a-component-with-generic-type.

Comment: @Blackhole So that's something like `export class DropdownComponent<T> {}`, and then `@Input() options: T[] = []`, yes? But what if I want to constrain it to a certain shape? Like I know T should be `{name: string; value: string}`, but in some cases, the given values will be a restricted set of that above type? Does that make sense? I don't want `T` to be absolutely anything in this case--I want it to conform to a shape, but I know sometimes the caller will have a known set of options that this component, ideally, would be aware of. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, indeed it is! You can use the `extends` keyword to restrict it to a certain shape: `export class DropdownComponent<T extends OptionType>{}`

Comment: heh...see my above edit. I hit "Add comment" too fast. (-;

Comment: I'd like to post a proper answer to this question, which I'm happy to do, but that won't give you the credit (other than me pointing it out in the answer). do you care about that? If so, you should post an answer rather than a comment. And thanks very much!!

Comment: Don't worry about it, you can post the answer :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my updated TS file for the component. There's not much to it, so I figured there's no harm in posting the whole thing.

The `selectedOption` line seems a little weird to me, but I think I understand it. My first inclination was to set it to `T`, but there's no guarantee that the default value I set in the code below will be a member of `T`, so it makes sense that it has to be `OptionType`.

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

type OptionType = {
  name: string;
  value: string;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.scss'],
})
export class DropdownComponent<T extends OptionType> implements OnInit {
  @Input() options: T[] = [];
  @Input() selectedOption: OptionType = { name: '', value: '' };

  @Output()
  onChangeEvent = new EventEmitter<T>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  onChange(option: T) {
    this.onChangeEvent.emit(option);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just a note: perhaps you can write `selectedOptionChange` instead of `onChangeEvent`. This would allow you to have a two-way binding from the parent `[(selectedOption)]="selectedOption"`